# Duvida sobre laço while em C?

Tags: c, while, do-while

Eu preciso saber porque que o 0 tem que ser digitado duas vezes para que o programa pare de percorrer o laço.

E acontece a mesma coisa quando uso o `do-while`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
    int num = 1, maior, menor, resultado, count = 0;
    while(num != 0){
        scanf("%d\n", &num);
        if(count == 0){
            maior = num;
            menor = num;
            count = 1;
        }else{
            if (num > maior && num != 0) {
                maior = num;
            }
            if (num < menor && num != 0) {
                menor = num;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", maior, menor);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: se colocou todo o programa, porque `count` não faz sentido e maior e menor não teve declaração também

Comment: não coloquei o programa todo, porque achei que nao fazia sentido, mas posso mudar.

Comment: menor nunca pode ser 0! já tem um erro conceitual não precisa do count nesse caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um erro meio bobo no `scanf` foi colocado um quebra de linha (`\n`) e não precisa dando esse problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
    int num = 1, maior = 0, menor = 99999999999;
    while(num != 0) {
        scanf("%d", &num);        
        if (num > maior) {
            maior = num;
        }
        if (num < menor && num != 0) {
            menor = num;
        }        
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", maior, menor);
    system("pause");
}
```

[Teste OnLine](http://cpp.sh/67pu7)

<sup>***Observação:*** *foi feito algumas alterações no código.*</sup>